# Android application crashes because of TextColor in main.xml

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, textcolor

I have developed a basic UI activity page in android with a TextView and EditText and a Button. I have set the TextView textColor to some hexadecimal value and my application crashes because of that, If I remove that textColor means the application runs perfectly.
Target sdk = 2.3
here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Enter search Key"
        android:textColor="#ff3300"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchkey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Key ..." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can we set textColor for TextView or is there something else is wrong with the code.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define color in the resources file in **res/values** folder

```
<resources>
<color name="mycolor">#33b5e5</color>
</resources>
```

And specify using **@color/mycolor** in Layout file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter search Key"
    android:textColor="@color/mycolor"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: It worked Thanks :) the problem with the one mine is I have mentioned the color values in small letter eg . ff3300 instead of FF3300 any way thanks for the help :)